# Could not find function "%.%"

Tags: r

I am building a Shiny app and using code from the Google Charts example. https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/google-charts.html  However, I keep running into a problem with function %.%. Is there a package I need to install?

Comment: `%.%` has been replaced by `%>%`

Answer (score 2):

That is the pipe operator that is used in dplyr and magrittr

A great overview: http://seananderson.ca/2014/09/13/dplyr-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in newer versions of dplyr (0.3.x+), the syntax `%.%` has been deprecated and replaced with `%>%`.

Also, check out this fantastic tutorial on dplyr
http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/11068_8bc42d6df61341b2bed45e9a9a3bf9f4.html